# perfect infinitive mode

Tags: infinitives, perfect-constructions

I have the task to change sentences to use the perfect infinitive. For example:

> I wish I were in Madagascar. → I would like to have been in Madagascar

How do I rephrase the sentences below  using the perfect infinitive?

> I haven’t seen Ali for ages! It seems he is ill.

This my attempt but it was not correct

> I couldn't seen Ali for ages! It seems he is ill

Comment: [Perfect infinitive with to (to have worked)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked)

Comment: "I wish I were in Madagascar. // I would like to have been in madagascar" this deserves its own  question. Although the second version is grammatical, the meanings of the two sentences are not the same.

Comment: i mean i was asked to change it to perfect infinitive and as a native speaker i have tried it so many times

Comment: The problem with this question is that there is no grammar transformation "to the perfect infinitive".  There are some transformations in grammar. For example you can transform from the present to the past tense.  Or you can transform from the active to the passive voice.  But there is no transformation from the present perfect to the perfect infinitive.  So I believe the question is unanswerable, or at least not phrased correctly....

Comment: ... Now the example given is **not** a transformation.  It is a rephrasing with similar but different meaning. It is a co-incidence that it happens to have a perfect infinitive. It is just luck that "wish" has similar meaning to "would like", and "would like" has an infinitive complement.

Comment: "he seems to have been ill".

Comment: “I would like to have been in Madagascar” does not make any sense. “I would have liked to have been in Madagascar” makes sense and is grammatical, but it does not mean “I want to be in Madagascar.” Where did this exercise come from?